# Battery drains to 0% when power off for 2 days?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I am on Ubuntu 16.10. Two days before I powered off my system correctly. Now, when I tried to power on, it was fully drained. I needed my charger to power on.

So, here is the case. When I switch off it via Ubuntu battery drains (in huge amounts ) while via Windows 10 there is only little bit change.

How can I save my battery ?

Comment: How do you switch it off?

Comment: Simple shut down...  option in right-top of ubuntu.

Comment: Battery drain can happen if the comp is suspended instead of powered off. If you leave an open program do you still get it open when you turn the comp on?

Comment: Nope . Not a case. I don't suspend and I closed my lid even after verifying it that shutdown is complete.

Comment: That's a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not entirely mine, more like a mashup of several answers I've read all over the Internet.

Main source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Battery_draining_problem

Aparently the "Wake On Lan" is the culprit of this drain issue.

Several ways of fixing this, my favorite would be creating a systemd service:

`/lib/systemd/system/wolfix.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=wolfix

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 wol d  #change eth0 according to your laptop nic
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable the service and good to go: `systemctl enable wolfix`

PD: This is assuming you are running 16.04 or newer, if not just add the `ethtool` line to `/etc/rc.local`, but keep in mind if some other program enable the wol feature before shutdown this fix will be useless.